# Why my Chart.js doesn't update and display in html? ASP.NET MVC using SignalR

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, chart.js

I am new and I want to update and display my chart.js in HTML with data got from my database using sinalr script. I used alert and it has value but still nothing in my chart. Can you check and show me what's the problem in my code. Thank you so much.
SignalR script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Proxy created on the fly
        var cus = $.connection.cusHub;

        //Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke
        cus.client.displayValue = function () {
            getData();
        };

        //Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tblValue');
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#Get").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $tbl.empty();
                $.each(data.listCus, function (i, model) {
                    $tbl.append
                        (
                            //'<tr>' +
                            //'<td>' + model.DeviceID + '</td>' +
                            //'<td>' + model.Value + '</td>' +
                            //'</tr>'
                            model.Value
                        );
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Display in HTML by tag ID :

```
<h2 id="tblValue" class="number" onchange="UpdateChart()">  </h2>
```

Chart.js code :

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("percent-chart2");
    var myVar = setInterval(GetValue, 5000);
    function GetValue() {
        const vals = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tblValue").innerHTML);
        //alert(vals);
        return vals;
    }
    const my_val = GetValue();
        if (ctx) {
        ctx.height = 209;
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        data: [my_val, my_val, my_val],
                        //data: [vals, vals, vals],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            '#00b5e9',
                            '#fa4251',
                            '#006400'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            '#00b5e9',
                            '#fa4251',
                            '#006400'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: [
                            0, 0, 0
                        ],
                        hoverBorderColor: [
                            'transparent',
                            'transparent',
                            'transparent'
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                labels: [
                    'STATION 1',
                    'STATION 2',
                    'STATION 3'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                cutoutPercentage: 87,
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontFamily: "Poppins,sans-serif"
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    titleFontFamily: "Poppins",
                    xPadding: 15,
                    yPadding: 10,
                    caretPadding: 0,
                    bodyFontSize: 16,
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function UpdateChart() {
        var updateValues = [my_val, my_val, my_val];
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = updateValues;
        myChart.update();
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. Add console.log() commands to your code to figure out which parts run and which parts don't, and what the actual values of your variables are.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I saw my problem. In chart.js code, my variable "my_val" is always NaN though "vals" has its value. Do you know what's wrong with my syntax         "const my_val = GetValue();" . I have just learned javascript recently in youtube so I get in many troubles. Thank you so much.

Comment: So alert(vals) does output the correct value? How does that even work, given that #tblValue seems to be a <h2> which you're filling with table data? Anyway, I guess the main problem is that you seem to think that `const my_val = GetValue();` somehow extends into the future. But that's not the case. That line runs once, when the page is loaded, then never again. You need to move it inside your UpdateChart function, as the first line.

Comment: Also, what is `onchange="UpdateChart()"` doing in an <h2> tag? Inline event handlers are bad practice in general, but onchange is commonly used for <input> or <textarea> or <select> elements; the browser fires the event when the user has changed the value. I don't see that firing for an <h2>, even if its content is changed.

Comment: You should also consider using proper variable names. "myVar", "my_val" does not tell you in any way what's actually stored in there.

Comment: Yeah you are right that line runs once so it's still NaN, but vals output value is correct. About "onchange" I just followed a video so maybe I used it in the wrong element. I think I function update in my code doesn't run. Maybe I should try another way. You are so nice! Thank you very much.